# NPM install task failing in Azure Devops, same code worked previously

Tags: azure-devops, npm-install, node-sass

I have `yaml` pipeline running a build in Azure Devops. The `Npm@1` task has started failing this morning. `npm install` works locally with npm version 6.14.5 and it's all green lights on [npm Status](https://status.npmjs.org/).

```
pool:
  name: 'Azure Pipelines'
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

stages:
  - stage: 
    variables:
      buildConfiguration: "Release"
      buildPlatform: "AnyCPU"
    jobs:
    - job: 
      steps:      
      - task: Npm@1
        displayName: 'npm install'
        inputs:
          workingDir: Azure/MySite/ClientApp
```

Here's where things start to go wrong in the logs:

```
1156 verbose pkgid node-sass@4.14.1
1157 verbose cwd /home/vsts/work/1/s/Azure/MySite/ClientApp
1158 verbose Linux 5.11.0-1021-azure
1159 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
1160 verbose node v16.13.0
1161 verbose npm  v8.1.0
1162 error code 1
1163 error path /home/vsts/work/1/s/Azure/MySite/ClientApp/node_modules/node-sass
1164 error command failed
1165 error command sh -c node scripts/build.js
1166 error Building: /usr/local/bin/node /home/vsts/work/1/s/Azure/MySite/ClientApp/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
1166 error make: Entering directory '/home/vsts/work/1/s/Azure/MySite/ClientApp/node_modules/node-sass/build'
1166 error   g++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/home/vsts/.node-gyp/16.13.0/include/node -I/home/vsts/.node-gyp/16.13.0/src -I/home/vsts/.node-gyp/16.13.0/deps/openssl/config -I/home/vsts/.node-gyp/16.13.0/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/home/vsts/.node-gyp/16.13.0/deps/uv/include -I/home/vsts/.node-gyp/16.13.0/deps/zlib -I/home/vsts/.node-gyp/16.13.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -fPIC -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=gnu++14 -std=c++0x -fexceptions -frtti -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/ast.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/ast.o ../src/libsass/src/ast.cpp
1166 error   g++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/home/vsts/.node-gyp/16.13.0/include/node -I/home/vsts/.node-gyp/16.13.0/src -I/home/vsts/.node-gyp/16.13.0/deps/openssl/config -I/home/vsts/.node-gyp/16.13.0/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/home/vsts/.node-gyp/16.13.0/deps/uv/include -I/home/vsts/.node-gyp/16.13.0/deps/zlib -I/home/vsts/.node-gyp/16.13.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -fPIC -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=gnu++14 -std=c++0x -fexceptions -frtti -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/ast_fwd_decl.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/ast_fwd_decl.o ../src/libsass/src/ast_fwd_decl.cpp
1166 error   g++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/home/vsts/.node-gyp/16.13.0/include/node -I/home/vsts/.node-gyp/16.13.0/src -I/home/vsts/.node-gyp/16.13.0/deps/openssl/config -I/home/vsts/.node-gyp/16.13.0/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/home/vsts/.node-gyp/16.13.0/deps/uv/include -I/home/vsts/.node-gyp/16.13.0/deps/zlib -I/home/vsts/.node-gyp/16.13.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -fPIC -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=gnu++14 -std=c++0x -fexceptions -frtti -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/backtrace.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/backtrace.o ../src/libsass/src/backtrace.cpp
1166 error   g++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/home/vsts/.node-gyp/16.13.0/include/node -I/home/vsts/.node-gyp/16.13.0/src -I/home/vsts/.node-gyp/16.13.0/deps/openssl/config -I/home/vsts/.node-gyp/16.13.0/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/home/vsts/.node-gyp/16.13.0/deps/uv/include -I/home/vsts/.node-gyp/16.13.0/deps/zlib -I/home/vsts/.node-gyp/16.13.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -fPIC -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=gnu++14 -std=c++0x -fexceptions -frtti -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/base64vlq.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/base64vlq.o ../src/libsass/src/base64vlq.cpp
```

There hadn't been any changes to the  `package.json` in several months. Going by the error message, I've narrowed the problem down to something to do with `note-sass` so here's a minimal `package.json` to reproduce the error.

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you change package versions recently?

Comment: No, my package.json has been modified for several months.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are two mysteries in the universe: 1) its spatial extent and 2) why does NPM fail?

```
10990 error path /home/vsts/work/1/s/Azure/MySite/ClientApp/node_modules/node-sass
10991 error command failed
10992 error command sh -c node scripts/build.js
10993 error Building: /usr/local/bin/node /home/vsts/work/1/s/Azure/MySite/ClientApp/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
10993 error make: Entering directory '/home/vsts/work/1/s/Azure/MySite/ClientApp/node_modules/node-sass/build'
```

From what I can see in your logs, it's matter of guessing, likeliness, and personal experience. Your pipeline is compiling `node-sass`, which I believe is the source of most evil in the nodejs world.

You likely didn't upgrade your dependencies, which **is** a problem in `node-sass`. Node-sass, in fact, is binary compiled to the nodejs version.

Azure DevOps normally upgrades the Node runtime **without telling anyone** (I posted a question yesterday, about SonarCloud integration).

Now, if you (or Azure) upgrade the Nodejs runtime, then you **must** find a more recent version of node-sass to use that is also compatible with your own app.

In your question, you **did** state what is the npm version you are running locally, but not the nodejs version, which is 16 on Azure.

As a workaround, you can instruct Azure to use a different Node version

```
      - task: NodeTool@0
        displayName: Install Node.js
        inputs:
          versionSpec: 'Your version e.g. 14.x'
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. I ran into the same issue and this saved me so much time!

Answer (score 7):

I still don't know why this started failing all of a sudden but I have resolved the problem by updating `node-sass` to version `6.0.1`.

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "node-sass": "6.0.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: See my answer for an explanation. Glad it worked

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain it.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue.  In my local I used node version(12.18.3)
and node-sass version(4.14.1). So in my local below commands are working fine.

```
npm start
npm run build
```

When I deploy code to Azure, there we are using node version(17.1) but the node-sass version(4.14.1) from the package.json.  But here we need to use node-sass version(7.x) instead of (4.x).

```
Reference Link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass
```

All you need to **uninstall** node-sass Just run this command to uninstall **node-sass**. **npm uninstall node-sass** Once uninstalled successfully then You just need to install sass instead of node-sass. Just run this command: **npm i -D sass** Now, My issue is resolved.