# Azure pipeline npm build failing for React

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, npm-build

I have been stuck at this for a while now and similar issues don't seem to help.

In Azure DevOps, the pipeline fails at the npm build level.

Agent: macOS-10.15

[image]

Can someone help please.

Comment: Is there any additional info with "View raw log"? And do you have the appropriate version of npm installed? I see you are specifying a Node version.

Comment: Hey @RobReagan Not really. The only thing i can point out is that the pipeline is using npm version 6.14.4 and locally I am using v6.14.10. Im not sure how to change the npm versions in a pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are using latest **macOS-10.15**. if not try to use **macOS-10.15** or **latest**.

By default, Azure DevOps upgrade the **Nodejs** runtime without notifying anyone. If you are trying to upgrade the **Nodejs** Make sure to use the **latest Nodejs** version. so that it will be the compatible with your application. In azure you have to specify the recent latest version otherwise it will take the default version

```yaml
#specify the latest node version.
- task: NodeTool@0
        displayName: Install Node.js
        inputs:
          versionSpec: 'Your node version e.g. 14.x'
```

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70200179/15997690) for more information

Comment: Hey @DelliganeshS-MT I am able to use the latest version but it still fails for some reason. Is there anything specific about that error message in the photo above?

Comment: can you share the recent error so that we can check further?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for a resolution.

I managed to fix my issue by creating a new YAML pipeline and for some reason this worked.